# Iphone 5 , UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown

Tags: uiinterfaceorientation, iphone-5

I am not able to rotate my view `PortraitUpsideDown` in my iPhone 5. I have used `supportedInterfaceOrientations(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll)` and `shouldAutorotate {return YES;}` and also checked `PortraitUpsideDown` orientation in the Project's Summary.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            self.ViewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
            self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ViewController];
        }
```

I have used `[self.window setRootViewController: self.navigationController]`. It is working all good for iPhone 4s but not in iPhone 5.

Comment: plz help i am in i huge mess........

Answer (score 0):

While this won't satisfy your question, I must add this:

***You should never let an iPhone or iPod Touch rotate to "upside down", ever.***

Only iPads should be allowed to do that.

Why?

Because these devices do not offer a lock button for landscape but only for portrait.

Now imagine you lay on your bed or couch on your side and want to use an iOS app that supports both portrait and landscape modes. Imagine you want to use this app in landscape mode. But as soon as you lay on the side, the iPhone is held upright, and it'll rotate to Portrait or UpsideDownPortrait. You cannot lock it to landscape unless the app prevents the Upsidedown mode!

Therefore, do let only iPads go into UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown, but not other devices, to let your users lock their iPhones into landscape mode when laying on their side.